# Passing model class between two screens in flutter using Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to pass model class between two screens using getx , i tried almost everything but always getting null vale in the destination screen , can you please help with this thank you

- This is how i pass data

```
  onTap: (){
      Get.to(() => const DetailsScreen(), arguments : {
        'data'  : data[index]
      });
    },
```

- This is how i receive data

```
  Result result = Result.fromJson(Get.parameters['data']);
```

- This is the error i'm getting

```
 The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("created_at")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get.arguments['data']` instead of `Get.parameters['data']` as you are passing arguments and not parameters.